# How do I add another value to a dictionary in MongoDB?

Tags: shell, mongodb, mongo-shell

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do, as I can't explain what I mean.

I execute this in the mongo CLI: `db.posts.insert({name: "Hello, world!, body: "Here's my first blog post. Happy reading!", comments: []})`. What I want to do is update that entry to add a comment to the `comments` dictionary.

How would I achieve this using `db.posts.update()`?

Comment: I've edited the question to make it a "real question". If this still doesn't meet your standards, please tell me what the problem is.

Comment: To add an element to an array, I think what you want is either $push or $addToSet: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating

Answer (score 17):

The OP's question and example don't match. He actually wants to insert a field into an array within the document, which means that

```
db.posts.update({name: "Hello, world!" }, { $push: {comments: "First comment!"}});
```

works just fine.

However, if you want to add a value or subdocument to a dictionary, you would use the `$set` command. Take this document as our example:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "538420b2862a656e9e99fc93"
    },
    "name": "Farmer John",
    "items": {
        "peaches": 5,
        "bananas": 10
    }
}
```

Let's say you wish to add `"apples": 2` to the items. The command would be

```
db.collection.update({"name": "Farmer John"},
                     {"$set": {"items.apples": 2}});
```

Your document would then look like:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "538420b2862a656e9e99fc93"
    },
    "name": "Farmer John",
    "items": {
        "peaches": 5,
        "bananas": 10,
        "apples: 2
    }
}
```

Note that this works with inserting subdocument as well, so we can modify the original example:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "538420b2862a656e9e99fc93"
    },
    "name": "Farmer John",
    "items": {
        "peaches": {
            "yellow": 5,
            "white": 3
        }
    }
}
```

And let's insert 4 granny smith apples and 8 fuji apples.

```
db.collection.update({"name": "Farmer John"},
                     {"$set": {"items.apples": {"fuji": 8, "granny smith": 4}}});
```

Our document would now be:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "538420b2862a656e9e99fc93"
    },
    "name": "Farmer John",
    "items": {
        "peaches": {
            "yellow": 5,
            "white": 3
        },
        "apples": {
            "fuji": 8,
            "granny smith": 4
        }
    }
}
```

One last comment: note that if the subdocument or field already exists, then it will be overridden by the `$set` command.

Answer (score -3):

For an object like:

```
{
  name: "Hello, world!",
  content: "This is my first post"
}
```

if you now run

```
db.posts.update({name: "Hello, world!"}, {name: "First post"});
```

this is what would be the result:

```
{
  title: "First post"
}
```

The content attribute will be removed as there is no replacement values provided.
I'm mentioning this as this is a common error.

So if you want to "add" an attribute, you need to run:

```
db.posts.update({name: "Hello, world!" }, { $push: {comments: "First comment!"}});
```

$push is used if you are appending data to an array. If its a normal field use $set.

Reference: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating